# search form leads to 404

Tags: functions, menus, filters, search

I'm using the follow code in my functions.php to add a search box to my primary nav menu -

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
        function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
            if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
                return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'><form action='search.php' id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search'></form></li>";

            return $items;
        }
```

The form adds to the nav menu ok, but any search attempt leads to a 404 message. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't submit directly to `search.php`. WordPress probably will not know what to do with that. You will have the same issue submitting directly to any theme file.

WordPress should pick up on the `s` parameter and process the search correctly if you just leave out the `action` attribute like so:

```
<form id='searchform' method='get'>
```

Untested, but I am fairly confident.